# LINQ OrderBy igorning case with true ASCII ordering

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, ascii

I'm trying to sort strings ("A", "_", "a") using LINQ in C# in ASCII order while ignoring case sensitivity. According to the [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), the strings I'm interested are:

- A = 65
- _ = 95
- a = 97

So I would expect the output to be

> A, _, a

However I tried all the StringComparer variations, none of them give me the desired output. The following is my test program and output:

```
    string[] words = { "A", "_", "a" };
    
    var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("OrdinalIgnoreCase: " + string.Join(", ", sortedWords));

    sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentCultureIgnoreCase: " + string.Join(", ", sortedWords));

    sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("InvariantCultureIgnoreCase: " + string.Join(", ", sortedWords));
```

output:

> OrdinalIgnoreCase: A, a, _
>
> CurrentCultureIgnoreCase: _, A, a
>
> InvariantCultureIgnoreCase: _, A, a

[.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V8kQ7P) here.

How do I sort the array to get "A, _, a" according to the ASCII ordering?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `StringComparer.Ordinal`. By using `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` you are ignoring the case, so probably it is silently converting everything to uppercase.

From MSDN:

[OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx):

> The StringComparer returned by the OrdinalIgnoreCase property treats the characters in the strings to compare as if they were converted to uppercase using the conventions of the invariant culture, and then performs a simple byte comparison that is independent of language.

and

[Ordinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal.aspx):

> The StringComparer returned by the Ordinal property performs a simple byte comparison that is independent of language.

Sample correctly formatted: http://ideone.com/0YTUdr

Comment: Just taken back my downvote, your first version of answer was  `Use StringComparer.Ordinal....` which looked confusing, like you are suggesting the same thing as first line

Comment: @Habib No, I was under the minimum size of the answer, and I was looking for some references around.

Answer (score -3):

Ignore case and sort words using LINQ can be done like this:

```
var sortedWords= words.OrderBy(w=>w, new CaseInsensitiveCompare());
```

Comment: Well, ignoring case is exactly what should *not* be done. See the accepted answer. And (worse) your code doesn't even compile.